# How can I set map extent in arcgis silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

Simple question but I don't know the answer. I want to set my map extent such that users see the map only in map extent and they don't allow to see greater extent. How can I set the extent map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the map extent to an envelope. The user cannot navigate outside the envelope defined in the behavior.

You are supposed to define a [ConstrainExtentBehavior](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/guide/behaviorsandactions.htm) behaviour:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Extent="-120,30,-60,60">
  . . . 
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <esriBehaviors:ConstrainExtentBehavior
      ConstrainedExtent="-120,30,-60,60"/> 
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</esri:Map>
```